# Outlook add-in with powerapps canvas app inside iframe not working

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, yeoman-generator, powerapps-canvas

So, I am trying to create an Outlook add-in that displays our power apps canvas app inside an iframe. Now, for some reason this iframe is capable of displaying power apps, but it won't go past the login screen.

When I run the add-in locally, and I view an email, I can see that power apps is asking me to login. Problem is that when I try to click the login button, a popup appears saying that it is unable to find the app "about" to open this link. Hence, it's requesting to get the app from the store, which it of course is unable to find.

Question is, how can I solve this or is there a method to display the canvas app in the Outlook add-in?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Billy Cottrell

## UPDATE 1:

So I just noticed what the login button does, it apparently opens a window with url about:blank.
Any idea if there is a way to fix this?

Comment: Hi Billy, what platform are you running Outlook on? Win32, Web, OWA?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT my apologies for the late response, but im running it on Win32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/use-iframe-and-web-resource-controls-on-a-form
Displaying a form within an IFrame embedded in another form is not supported.

It's not supported.  Some have it working as long as SSO is not used.  Still, it's not supported and if it works it may break at any time.  I verified this with a PowerApps Escalation Engineer at Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

@Billy Cottrell, do you have the domain for the power apps specified in the AppDomains section of the manifest. Here is [some documentation related to this topic](https://@Billy%20Cottrell,%20do%20you%20have%20the%20domain%20for%20the%20power%20apps%20specified%20in%20the%20AppDomains%20section%20of%20the%20manifest.%20Here%20is%20some%20documentation%20related%20to%20this%20topic:%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-in-manifests?tabs=tabid-1#:%7E:text=It%20applies%20only%20to%20the%20root%20pane%20of%20the%20add%2Din.%20If%20there%20is%20an%20iframe%20embedded%20in%20the%20add%2Din%20page%2C%20the%20iframe%20can%20be%20directed%20to%20any%20URL%20regardless%20of%20whether%20it%20is%20listed%20in%20%3CAppDomains%3E%2C%20even%20in%20desktop%20Office.).